# Convergence in distribution to delta

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let us assume $f_n\in S'(\mathbb{R}^k)$ (Schwartz space) such that $f_n\to\delta_t$ in distribution sense. That is, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}f_n(s)F(s)\mathrm{d}s\to F(t)$$ for all $F\in S(\mathbb{R}^k)$. Fix $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^k)$ (with no necesarily compact support). Is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}f_n(s)g(s)\mathrm{d}s\to g(t)$?

Comment: The first problem is that we cannot be sure that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}f_n(s)g(s)\mathrm{d}s$ is even defined. So we should add that as a criterium.

Comment: @md2perpe I edited it.

Comment: That's still not enough. The $f_n$ might be non-$L^2$ making the integrals diverge.